# Access internal JS file from external script

Tags: javascript, external

I am writing an A/B test, and I am writing a script that will modify the original page to create the second version of the page. I do not have access to the site source files, I can only modify the external script. The site's main.js has Google Maps code that I'd rather not duplicate and I'd like to accessit in order to use the existing functionality. Is it possible to access the site's internal main.js file from my script and use code that exists inside it?

Comment: That depends on how the JS is written and what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes, but there are no guarantees it will work as you expect it to. We would need to see the code, and an example of what you're trying to do, to determine if it would work.

Comment: The current page is a store locator search, which sends the user to a results page with location info and Google Map. I'm trying to modify the search so it displays the search results/map in a modal on the same page via AJAX. There's a lot of Google Maps configuration code in the main.js that I'd like to use. Here's a chunk of code I'd like to use from main.js:                  `var gmap = {
    firstLoad: true,
    stores: window.storesArray || [],
    storesById: [],
    stories: window.storiesArray || [],
    layerService: {},
    position: {}
};

gmap.map = {};`